# uicollectionview in a navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a main viewcontroller with a button , when clicked should show up a uicollectionview. 
I have used a navigationcontroller to navigate between the 2.
However, i am unable to bring up the UICollectionView.

I get the following error

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'watchViewController''*

Here is the code

```
watchViewController  *watchVC = [[watchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"watchViewController" bundle:nil];

AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UINavigationController *watchNavCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:watchVC];
[watchNavCtrl setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mainVCObj]];

appDelegate.window.rootViewController = watchNavCtrl;
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[mainVCObj.navigationController pushViewController:watchVC animated:YES];
```

I would appreciate if you could help me out where am i going wrong

Comment: Which line of code is causing the crash? Where do you call the `watch` method or access the `watch` property on an instance of the `MainVC` class?

Comment: actually the entire code works fine . it crashes somewhere within the internal objective-c code.                                      i read somewhere the issue could be with the button image. i deleted it and readded and now it works fine. however, now i get a different error. i have modified the question to show up that error

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get the fix. but quite puzzled by it
i had to set the initWithNibName=nil in

watchViewController  *watchVC = [[watchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"watchViewController" bundle:nil];

changed to

watchViewController  *watchVC = [[watchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

the above change worked. i did all the tricks before this mentioned in other posts. 
readded the nib file
added to bundle buildphases
made sure it is not case sensitive

but eventually the problem was somewhere else
anybody any idea on this logic?

Thanks